# How to calculate Jensen's Inequality

Tags: probability, integration, convex-analysis

How would one show that $\mathbb{E}\Big[f(X)\Big] \geq f\Big[\mathbb{E}(X)\Big]$ for the convex function f(x)=x$^{2}$ ?

Comment: Hint: Have you ever tried applying the _linearity of expectation_ theorem to $E[(X-E[X])^2]$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate no? I don't understand how that helps..

Comment: Trying again, can you explain from first principles why it is that the numerical value of $E[(X-E[X])^2]$ is a nonnegative number? Can you show, using the linearity of expectation, that $$E[(X-E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - \left(E[X]\right)^2 ~??$$ Can you put these ideas together in some way to verify that Jensen's inequality holds for the function $x^2$?